# SignalR Mapping Users to Connections Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

In SignalR '[Mapping Users to connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)' they have a pretty good implementation for mapping users to connections using `Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>` however, I can't see the point of this portion of code in the `Add` method:

```
 lock (connections)
 {
      connections.Add(connectionId);
 }
```

1) What's the point of adding an element to the local variable `connections` just before ending the method?

2) What's the point of having `lock` inside a `lock`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TraQ6.GeoTrack
{
    public class ConnectionMapping<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =
            new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _connections.Count;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    connections = new HashSet<string>();
                    _connections.Add(key, connections);
                }

                lock (connections) // here
                {
                    connections.Add(connectionId); // here
                } 
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return connections;
            }

            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }

        public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Remove(connectionId);

                    if (connections.Count == 0)
                    {
                        _connections.Remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) *connections* is a local variable, but actually is a reference to an object, the SAME object that was added to the *_connections* dictionary.
So even when it seems to be only a "local variable" it's actually a reference to a managed object that won't be disposed at the end of the method because it is referenced in the dictionary.

2) I'm not sure if this is really necessary, but the outer "lock (_connection)" will lock the whole dictionary, and the *lock (connection)* will lock only the current hashset.

Answer (score 0):

The add is important to add a new connectionId for an existing user.

1. User1 creates a connection (conn1). You create a new entry in the Dictonary with `User1, {Conn1}`
2. User1 creates another connection, so you retrieve the existing connections by userId and add it, it becomes `User1, {Conn1, Conn2}`

I'm not sure why you'd need to lock it twice.

Comment: But `connections` is a local variable right? They are not adding to `_connections`

Comment: No, whenever you connect to a hub, you have a connectionid for each user per hub, so one user can have multiple connectionids if he/she is connected to different hubs.